# Cross Validation - One class classification

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I am trying to perform one-class classification such that I only have positive data during training time and negative data is only available at testing time. If I use, One-class SVM or any other one-class method, there is a common problem to estimate parameters with cross-validation approach, because during training phase we don't have negative data. A problem that I feel can occur by estimating parameters using only positive data is 'over-fitting' during training or in other words, if we just care about parameters that gives us lowest false-negative rate, we may end up with parameter(s) with zero false-negative but high false-positive rate during testing.

My question is, can you please suggest me a parameter estimation method with CV or refer to any paper that deals with this scenario. Most of the google search and literature review didn't solved my problem. To simplify this problem, many researchers assume some outliers (or artificially generate them), but in my case, I can't say anything about the negative concept as I only know what positive data looks like.
Your feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like [you already looked at this paper](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/ManevitzY01.pdf) but it's worth a comment anyway, [so is this one](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic274302.files/Dan.Nick.pdf) (slightly more recent).

Comment: @RogerRowland: Thanks for your effort. I think this is an open question where people either generate artificial outliers or treat some part of positive data as negative. The former requires strong assumption over negative class, so I am trying to look at the latter approach.

Comment: @RogerRowland links are not available :( can you update them? or maybe give their names, thankyou!